# Has Daenerys got the gold?

Tags: game-of-thrones

After Daenerys's attack in "The Spoils of War" (*Game of Thrones*, S07E04) against the Lannisters, is she able to take all the gold that the Lannisters take away from the Tyrells?

In that case, would all of Cersei's plans and her searching for support from the Iron Bank be going to collapse?

Answer (score 16):

**No**

It was mentioned by lord Tarly, before the battle begins:

> Tarly: **All the gold's safely through
>   the gates of King's Landing**.
>
> Jaime: Good.
>
> T: We need to get the last of these wagons over the Blackwater Rush before nightfall.
>
> If the head of the line is ambushed, the tail will never be able
>   to reinforce in time....

Answer (score 11):

## No.

At the beginning of the scene, Lord Tarly explained that all the gold had made it into King's Landing,

> "All the gold’s safely through the gates of King’s Landing."

They were only trying to get everything else across the river when Daenerys attacked.